# Get name of Heroku database through database URL

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Given a Heroku PostGRES database URL, I want to get the project & database name (e.g. myapplication::amber).

How can I do this?

The database names are Heroku slugs like `d153lzz9no123` that aren't descriptive of what database and project I'm viewing. That is why I would like the name which is usually in the format `<project-name>:<postgres-db-level>`.